# SQL aggregate function from subselect too slow

Tags: mysql, sql

this query takes too much time..

```
 SELECT sum(res.opportunities_sum) as opportunities_sum,
        res.traffic_source_id, sum(res.ad_request_sum) as ad_request_sum, 
        sum(res.ad_impression_sum) as ad_impression_sum, sum(res.ad_start_sum) as ad_start_sum
 FROM 
 (
     SELECT sum(ev.opportunities) as opportunities_sum,
            ev.traffic_source_id,
            (select sum(ad_request) FROM events_ad_source a
             where a.event_id = ev.id) as ad_request_sum, 
            (select sum(ad_impression) FROM events_ad_source a
             where a.event_id = ev.id) as ad_impression_sum, 
            (select sum(ad_start) FROM events_ad_source a
             where a.event_id = ev.id) as ad_start_sum 
     FROM events ev 
     inner join user_agents
         on ev.user_agent_id = user_agents.id 
     WHERE ev.traffic_source_id IN (6,1,5,10,9,8,7) AND
           ev.date BETWEEN '01-01-2017' AND '02-16-2017'
     GROUP BY ev.traffic_source_id, ev.id 
     ORDER BY ev.traffic_source_id
) as res
GROUP BY res.traffic_source_id
```

but the inner query result fetching in less then a second so...

i need to optimize this query someway ..

EDIT:
i have 3 tables

events

events_ad_source

user_agents

when i try to join between events and events_ad_source

the sum of events.opportunities return results that calculated by the number of rows that in the events_ad_source,

cause for each row in events,

there is a lot of rows in events_ad_source

(i cant add the table definitions right now)

---- I run EXPLAIN - this is the results ----

```
QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                      |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
GroupAggregate  (cost=12804.13..58865668.76 rows=200 width=36)                                                                                                  |
  Group Key: ev.traffic_source_id                                                                                                                               |
  ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=12804.13..58864073.65 rows=70716 width=12)                                                                                          |
        Group Key: ev.traffic_source_id, ev.id                                                                                                                  |
        ->  Sort  (cost=12804.13..12980.92 rows=70716 width=12)                                                                                                 |
              Sort Key: ev.traffic_source_id, ev.id                                                                                                             |
              ->  Hash Join  (cost=1.36..7108.04 rows=70716 width=12)                                                                                           |
                    Hash Cond: (ev.user_agent_id = user_agents.id)                                                                                              |
                    ->  Seq Scan on events ev  (cost=0.00..5802.86 rows=159110 width=16)                                                                        |
                          Filter: ((date >= '2017-01-01'::date) AND (date <= '2017-02-16'::date) AND (traffic_source_id = ANY ('{6,1,5,10,9,8,7}'::integer[]))) |
                    ->  Hash  (cost=1.16..1.16 rows=16 width=4)                                                                                                 |
                          ->  Seq Scan on user_agents  (cost=0.00..1.16 rows=16 width=4)                                                                        |
        SubPlan 1                                                                                                                                               |
          ->  Aggregate  (cost=277.39..277.40 rows=1 width=4)                                                                                                   |
                ->  Seq Scan on events_ad_source a  (cost=0.00..277.39 rows=1 width=4)                                                                          |
                      Filter: (event_id = ev.id)                                                                                                                |
        SubPlan 2                                                                                                                                               |
          ->  Aggregate  (cost=277.39..277.40 rows=1 width=4)                                                                                                   |
                ->  Seq Scan on events_ad_source a_1  (cost=0.00..277.39 rows=1 width=4)                                                                        |
                      Filter: (event_id = ev.id)                                                                                                                |
        SubPlan 3                                                                                                                                               |
          ->  Aggregate  (cost=277.39..277.40 rows=1 width=4)                                                                                                   |
                ->  Seq Scan on events_ad_source a_2  (cost=0.00..277.39 rows=1 width=4)                                                                        |
                      Filter: (event_id = ev.id)                                                                                                                |
```

-------------TABLE DATA---------------

EVENTS :

```
id     |traffic_source_id |opportunities |date       |
-------|------------------|--------------|-----------|
318192 |5                 |1             |2017-02-12 |
318193 |5                 |1             |2017-02-12 |
318194 |5                 |1             |2017-02-12 |
318195 |5                 |3             |2017-02-12 |
318196 |5                 |4             |2017-02-12 |
318197 |5                 |1             |2017-02-12 |
318198 |5                 |1             |2017-02-12 |
```

EVENTS_AD_SOURCE:

```
id    |event_id |traffic_source_id |ad_request |
------|---------|------------------|-----------|
17997 |318195   |5                 |1          |
17993 |318192   |5                 |1          |
17994 |318192   |5                 |1          |
17995 |318192   |5                 |1          |
17996 |318193   |5                 |1          |
17998 |318196   |5                 |4          |
17999 |318197   |5                 |1          |
18000 |318198   |5                 |1          |
18001 |318198   |5                 |1          |
```

SO THE RESULT OF SUM(OPPORTUNITIES), SUM(AD_REQUEST) 
SHOULD BE

12 | 12

Comment: _this query takes too much time_ What is too much time and what was expected? Have you used EXPLAIN? There could be thousand reasons for that. bad data design, no index, bad query, wrong config etc

Comment: @bub It is fairly clear that there are some nested correlated subqueries in there.  We should use joins insteads, with indices, to improve performance.

Comment: Maybe if you post the table definitions and describe what the query is supposed to be doing it would help.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sure I see the bad guys :) maybe there is more than the subqueries which has to be improved. But I would suggest to run EXPLAIN first

Comment: @bub from the subselect i get about 156,000 results, so there is a lot of data, but.

Comment: @shayroubeni 156,000 result should be very easy to get handled by mysql if db designed well

Comment: Rather than explaining a poorly structured query, I would recommend trying to understand what the goal of the query is, and then rewriting it.

Comment: i'll try to provide more data of this topic, 
as far as i can.. give me some time (its my first question here :) )

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen 2 possible ways, one result

Comment: I'd try do convert all those correlated sub-queries to left joins instead.

Comment: I edit the post guys, hope it will help all of you that try to help! 
thanks anyway !

Comment: Why do you add up per `traffic_source_id` + `events.id` only to add up again per `traffic_source_id`? And you multiply `opportunities` with the number of agents for the event and call this `opportunities_sum`. Is this on purpose? The `ORDER BY` is completely superfluous by the way.

Comment: do you have sample data. you can post it on http://pastebin.com/

Comment: BTW: your date literals look dubious. I'd change 'DD-MM-YYYY'  or 'MM-DD-YYYY' (whatever it is) to 'YYYY-MM-DD' to get it safe.

Comment: i add table data, maybe now it will be easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking to your code  way you simple  don't perform only the subselect  ..

fist you could reduce the second level subselect

```
SELECT sum(res.opportunities_sum) as opportunities_sum,
        res.traffic_source_id, sum(res.ad_request_sum) as ad_request_sum, 
        sum(res.ad_impression_sum) as ad_impression_sum, sum(res.ad_start_sum) as ad_start_sum
 FROM 
 (
   SELECT 
        sum(ev.opportunities) as opportunities_sum
      , ev.traffic_source_id
      , t1.ad_request_sum 
      , t1.ad_impression_sum
      , t1.ad_start_sum
    from FROM events ev 
    LEFT JOIN  ( select  
        event_id 
     ,  sum(ad_request) as ad_request_sum
     ,  sum(ad_impression) as ad_impression_sum
     , sum(ad_start) as ad_start_sum 
    FROM events_ad_source a
    group by event_id
    ) t1 on t1.event_id = ev.id
    inner join user_agents on ev.user_agent_id = user_agents.id 
   WHERE ev.traffic_source_id IN (6,1,5,10,9,8,7) AND
         ev.date BETWEEN '01-01-2017' AND '02-16-2017'
   GROUP BY ev.traffic_source_id, ev.id 
   ORDER BY ev.traffic_source_id
) as res
GROUP BY res.traffic_source_id
```

but do the fact that seems  yours  external select perform  aggregation function  on already aggregated  function for the same group by 
you could get the result withou external select

```
   SELECT 
        sum(ev.opportunities) as opportunities_sum
      , ev.traffic_source_id
      , t1.ad_request_sum 
      , t1.ad_impression_sum
      , t1.ad_start_sum
    from FROM events ev 
    LEFT JOIN  ( select  
        event_id 
     ,  sum(ad_request) as ad_request_sum
     ,  sum(ad_impression) as ad_impression_sum
     , sum(ad_start) as ad_start_sum 
    FROM events_ad_source a
    group by event_id
    ) t1 on t1.event_id = ev.id
    inner join user_agents on ev.user_agent_id = user_agents.id 
   WHERE ev.traffic_source_id IN (6,1,5,10,9,8,7) AND
         ev.date BETWEEN '01-01-2017' AND '02-16-2017'
   GROUP BY ev.traffic_source_id, ev.id 
   ORDER BY ev.traffic_source_id
```

Comment: Your derived query lacks event_id both in `select` and `group by` and contains a `where` clause that must be removed.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner   . then i'm sorry but i can't uderstand  your previous   comment  .. .. if you can  .. please explain better

Comment: @ThorstenKettner   partially understand  (the where in reduce  subselect is unuseful because the on clause )   answer updated .

Comment: `INNER JOIN  ( select ... from events_ad_source a where a.event_id = ev.id) t1 on t1.event_id = ev.id`: You cannot access `ev` inside t1. Also you access `t1.event_id` in the on clause, but you don't select `event_id` inside t1.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner    many thanks  ... added  (and grouped )  event_id

Comment: @scaisEdge almost there ! 
the sum of ev.opportunities calculated only for rows that have an event_id, in the events_ad_source table,

so if there is an opportunity in events table with id X it will not calculated,
and all the opportunities that i fetched are by event_id

Comment: i add table data, maybe now it will be easy

Comment: @scaisEdge 

`traffic_source_id |opportunities_sum |ad_request_sum |ad_impression_sum |ad_start_sum |
------------------|------------------|---------------|------------------|-------------|
5                 |11                |12             |11                |11           |`

Comment: I have update the answer using LEFT JOIN (instead of INNER JOIN) because in your sample there is a id 318194   that don't match the event_id  .. in the related  table  .. soif you need  also the value for not match  you should use left  join